# Disable viewing iframed file

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

Is it possible to iframe a file on your server,that if it's being viewed using direct url (www.page.com/iframed_file.html) user gets 403(forbidden) message?

---

Example:
User goes to page.com gets iframed index.
user goes to page.com/iframed.html gets 403 error

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by referer, but HTTP referers can be easily forged so it's no guarantee:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?page\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^iframed\.html$ - [L,F]
```